# MVC4 - how to best setup model for school names that will always be drop downs

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want part of my model to have "school" and "semester". They will both be drop downs. 
In the future, I would like to be able to easily add more schools in.

Do I just want to use this? and if so, how do I handle what shows up on the drop down anytime .DropDownFor is called without having to make the list on each page?

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select a school")]
    [Display(Name = "School")]
    public string school { get; set; }
```

I saw an example that used SelectList instead of school, but a little confused on how to use that, since the information stored in the database would just be one school name, not a whole list. Is SelectList the correct type to use in this situation? Is there something else besides selectlist and string I should use? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use both select list and string. `SelectList` will hold options of drop down, and the `school` will keep user selected value

Something like this

```
//view model
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SchoolsSelectList { get; set; }
public string School { get; set; }



//controller action
public ActionResult Create()
{
     SchoolSemesterViewModel model = new SchoolSemesterViewModel();
     model.SchoolsSelectList = SchoolRepository.Schools.Select(x=> new SelectListItem()
     {
          Text = x.SchoolName,
          Value = x.SchoolName
     });

     return View(model);
}

//view

 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.School, Model.SchoolsSelectList)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
Where do I store the names of the schools in this example?

Comment: Anywhere you want to. In the example, I used SchoolRepository that queries database to get list of shools and then transfers them into select list - no more hardcoding school names. You may implement any kind of data store.